# Stating minuscule uncertainty

Tags: dataset, uncertainty

I have calculated my main data, according to good manners with numbers it has as many decimal numbers (two in this case) as the data we collected in measurement. But the associated uncertainty I calculated has first significant number at sixth place.

How should I state it? Could it be like $5.25$$\pm$$0.000003$?

PS: I haven't studied math primarily in english, so if there is any problem with my word usage, let me know, I will hapilly learn something new!

Comment: The question to me is not how you express such uncertainty but how you could possibly quantify it in the first place. If i measure people's heights as 1.23 m or whatever, with say a large rigid rule, then I'm deliberately not being more precise because I know that more decimal places would be much harder work and have no scientific or practical interest any way. But I could not possibly get at uncertainty 4 orders of magnitude more precise without a massive number of replications and using a quite different measurement protocol.

Comment: (contd) So I can't see such a report as anything but contradictory. Rounding always implies that the last decimal place given is fallible.

Comment: When computing uncertainty, remember that there is already $\pm 0.005$ uncertainty in the data from the start (due to rounding). If this is indeed dampened this much, it would be quite extraordinary - usually the uncertainty grows with the operations performed.

Comment: Wel, I see what you mean. Measured data (1.23 for instance) are used for linear regression, outputs are slope and intercept (which both have, as a result of computation, 6 or more decimal numbers, slope has first significant number at 4th place as well) and I calculated uncertainties for these parameters. That's the merit of my question.

Comment: Standard errors have nothing to do with uncertainty associated with measurement error unless (exceptionally) you're using methods that include explicit quantification of your measurement error. A common or garden regression routine can know nothing about inherent measurement error.

Comment: Could the exception be fulfilled by using weighted LR (that's what I did, should've mentioned it)? + what's garden regression?

Comment: @GinnyTheGrey: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170977/what-is-the-origin-of-common-or-garden

Comment: @Scortchi hey, I really did learn something new. Thank you!